# Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 REST API - List filesystems - "code": "AuthorizationPermissionMismatch

Tags: rest, azure-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

I try to get list filesystems and their properties in the Azure Storage account using request:

```
https://<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/?resource=account
```

with one header [Bearer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lwhD.png)
and get response

```
 "error": {
    "code": "AuthorizationPermissionMismatch",
    "message": "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this ******"
}
```

But when I make request for list paths:

```
https://<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<filesystem>?recursive=true&resource=filesystem
```

I get a response with correct data.

Can you give me some advice on what is wrong?

P.s. My auth params.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDBcW.png)

Comment: Hi, @AnsumanBal-MT ! For the list filesystem, I use only "resource" = "account"

Comment: I mean in the headers if you have included x-ms-version and x-ms-date and also may i know what is the RBAC role assigned to the service principal ?

Comment: I tried with x-ms-version. The response was the same. I am a Contributor to this storage account.

Comment: so you are using implicit flow to get the bearer token or client credentials?

Comment: I add my auth params to the description. Thank you fo response!

Comment: Ok! Give me a few hours! Because I still get AuthorizationPermissionMismatch. But I think that it's trouble with my clientID.

Comment: you have added the role right for the client ? and yes the client id you are using is not the correct one , its the expose api link ,, you can remove api:// from that and it will be the client ID or better directly use the client ID from portal only.. but the main solution is the role `storage account contributor ` for the same client to resolve the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the same request in my environment by getting the token using client ID and secret. I received the same error as you are getting :

[image]

**As a Solution** ,

1. I added `Storage Account Contributor` role to the Service Principal
   which I am using to get the bearer token as below:

   [image]
2. Then , I get the bearer token using below client_credentials method:

   [image]
3. After the above, When I perform the same request again then it gets
   successful:

   [image]

Comment: Tenant ID and directory ID in your URL - it's the same?

Comment: yes its the same @YakivStoikov

Comment: Awesome! Now it gives me the correct response. )))

Comment: Glad to be of help @YakivStoikov!!!